# How can i prevent submitting an empty value? I'm a beginner. any advice?

Tags: javascript, function, validation

I try to put a simple validation check on my JavaScript code. but it seems it doesnt work. Because it submits even the input field is empty and outputting like the screenshot shown below. please help. i just want to upload to this to my portfolio.

here is my HTML tags

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div class="due-container">
        <label>Due Date: </label>
        <input type="date" class="due" required />
        <!-- <span id="error-message" class="error hidden">Error Message</span> -->
      </div>
      <div class="past-container">
        <label>Past Due: </label>
        <input type="date" class="past" required />
        <!-- <span id="error-message" class="error hidden">Error Message</span> -->
      </div>
      <div class="monthly-container">
        <label>Monthly Amortization: </label>
        <input type="number" class="monthly" required />
        <!-- <span id="error-message" class="error hidden">Error Message</span> -->
      </div>
      <button class="check">Calculate</button>
      <button type="reset" class="reset">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <div class="modal hidden">
      <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
      <h3>Reminder:</h3>
      <p id="delayed-days"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay hidden"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my javascript code:
I put the screenshot at the bottom. thanks

```
     'use strict';
            
            const due = document.querySelector('.due');
            const past = document.querySelector('.past');
            const monthly = document.querySelector('.monthly');
            const btn = document.querySelector('.check');
            const errMsg = document.querySelector('span');
            
            //modal buttons
            const myModalBtn = document.querySelector('.modal');
            const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-modal');
            const overlayBtn = document.querySelector('.overlay');
            
            const delayedDaysEl = document.getElementById('delayed-days');
            
            //ms to days conversion
            const second = 1000;
            const minute = second * 60;
            const hour = minute * 60;
            const day = hour * 24;
            
            btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              calcDate();
              openModal();
            });
            
            //modal close-button function
            closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
              closeModal();
            });
            
            function calcDate() {
              const dueValue = due.value;
              const pastValue = past.value;
            
              const dueDate = new Date(dueValue).getTime();
              const pastDate = new Date(pastValue).getTime();
              const gap = pastDate - dueDate;
            
              const daysValue = gap / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
            
              if (dueDate > pastDate) {
                alert('Check the date properly!');
              }
            
              if (monthly === '') {
                alert('Please enter your monthly payment');
              }
            
              delayedDaysEl.textContent = `You're ${daysValue} days delayed`;
            }
            
            function openModal() {
              myModalBtn.classList.remove('hidden');
              overlayBtn.classList.remove('hidden');
            }
            
            function closeModal() {
              myModalBtn.classList.add('hidden');
              overlayBtn.classList.add('hidden');
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Add the validation handler to the form's submit listener, not the submit button as forms can be submitted without clicking the button. That way no matter how the form is submitted, the handler is called and it cancels the actual submit action rather than events stemming from the click on the button. Also, the validation function *calcDate* doesn't return a useful value so how will the form submit or not depending on the outcome of validation?

Comment: oh, thanks for your response. ill try your to apply what said on your comment. hope it works bro, thanks again. godbless u bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If required is not working then you can apply a check when you click on calculate button if past or due or monthly field(any of) is empty then you will get a alert ; If user fills all the fields then only it will calculate.

**You can replace the little part of  the code Below something like.**

```js
btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (due.value !== "" && past.value !== "" && monthly.value!=="") {
        calcDate();
      openModal();
      
    } 
    else{
        alert('either past or due or monthly fleid  empty');
    }
  });
```

Comment: damn bro thanks.. you give my mind an idea on what should i do to my code to make it work!! Im just a newbie. but thanks for this bro! godbless you!

Comment: Thanks @Anojay , for making a complement & you can also accept and like my answer that will be a bonus for me .

Comment: ya bro sure. it works perfectly in my case. although i change some of the code but you give me the structure to make it work! thanks again Gulshan Aggarwal.

Answer (score 0):

Also, write the type for your **calculate button** because if not provided it will act as a submit button and it will refresh the page every time you click.